# Difference of measurement filtered by tag in InfluxDB

Tags: time-series, influxdb

In InfluxDB v1.3, I have a measurement with one field and a tag that can take two values.

I would like to compute `(x where mytag=y) - (x where mytag=z)`, using the last value of each series when needed (something like an http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/aj). I would like to do this in one query, if possible.

If the above is not possible, is there a different schema (e.g. using separate measurements) where what I would like to do is feasible? If so, can you please elaborate on the structure and the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT difference(mean(x))
FROM <measurement>
WHERE time > now() - 1h and (mytag='y' OR mytag='x')
GROUP BY time(60s), mytag
```

Functions like difference require an aggregate query (`group by time()`) as well as an aggregation function for the values within the grouped window (`mean` above).

Difference then shows the differences between sequential aggregated values for the time period specified, additionally grouped by the two tag values specified.

These can be adjusted depending on your data.